# C# priority queue, generic type <T> conversion

Tags: c#, generics, queue, priority-queue

```
public class PriorityQueue<T> : IPriorityQueue<T> 
                            where T : IComparable
```

So, I've made a priority queue class with the Header above and I'm attempting to use it with another class.

```
        private static PriorityQueue<Order> PQ;
```

It seems like this should work perfectly fine, but I'm receiving this error.

> My `namespace.Order` cannot be used as type parameter `T` in the generic method `namespace.PriorityQueue<T>`. There is no implicit conversion from `namespace.Order` to `System.IComparable`

I can't really discern what that is telling me to do. Does this mean that my `IComparable` implementation isn't sufficient for this purpose, or is it some sort of bad syntax I'm using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It says, that your generic type parameter (i.e. `Order` type) should implement [IComparable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable.aspx) interface.

Comment: Doh. Thank you. I had commented my interfaces out and forgot to remove them afterwards. Thanks again.